# Formula Help on Process Builder

Tags: process-builder

I am trying to populate the Campaign ID on an Opportunity record that will be created via process builder.  I have this formula, but it is not right.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
If(
    ISPICKVAL([Lead].LeadSource, ‘Content - Selling Resources’),
    ’701S0000000eQdFIAU’,
    IF(
        NOT(ISPICKVAL([Lead].LeadSource, ‘Content - Selling Resources’)),
        ’701S0000000ePIEIA2’
    )
```

Comment: I've taken the liberty of formatting your formula a little differently. Based on what I see, your formula should be giving you an error when you try to save it. If you are getting an error message, it's always a good idea to include it (the entire error) word-for-word. The error message might not be helpful to you, but it can help the more experienced eyes here narrow down the issue.

Comment: Breaking formulas up into smaller pieces (and using indentation) like I have here is also a good way to do a quick check to see if there's anything obviously wrong. In this case, it looks like your nested `IF` is missing the third parameter (the `else` expression/value), and your outer `IF` isn't closed. The nested `IF` also looks redundant. This is basically what Ricky's answer tells you, but again, it becomes easier to see when you break things up and use indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what has happened here is a bit of an overcomplicated formula. Try this:

`IF(ISPICKVAL([Lead].LeadSource, 'Content - Selling Resource'),'701S0000000eQdFIAU',701S0000000ePIEIA2)`

So this way if the formula returns `TRUE` it will pick the first value, if `FALSE` then the second value. Since you don't have anymore conditions this should work.